# C# 2010 Ms=Accress 2003

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, ms-access-2003

My application with C#2010 and database in Access2003, I want to insert new recrord into my table by the it has an error:

> "syntax error in insert into statement"

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         String ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\New.mdb";
         OleDbConnection myconection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
         try
         {      
                 OleDbCommand mycomand = new OleDbCommand();
                 mycomand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Refugees Characteristic(Nr,First Name,Last Name,Birthday,Country,City,Insurance Nr,Gander,Marital status,Nr of Children,Address,Mother Tongue,Other Languages,Phone Nr,Enter to Austria,Education,Skills,Picture) VALUES (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16,@p17,@p18)";
                 mycomand.Parameters.Clear();
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", IdTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", FirstTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", LasttextBox.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", BirthdayTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", CountryTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", CityTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", InsuranceTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", GanderBox.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", marriedTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", ChildnumTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", AddressTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", MotherTongTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", OtherlanTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", phonNumberTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", EnterTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", EducationTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p17", SkillsTxt.Text);
                 mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p18", PicLocationtxt.Text);
                // mycomand.Connection = null;
                 mycomand.Connection = myconection;
                 myconection.Open();
                 mycomand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 MessageBox.Show("New Record is Added");
                 myconection.Close();
                 myconection.Dispose();
                 mycomand.Dispose();
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
```

Comment: Put square brackets around your column names that have spaces in them `[marital status]` (also, don't do this to begin with... `MaritalStatus` would have been better column name)

Answer (score 0):

If your table names and column names are two words, you need to use them with square brackets like `[Refugees Characteristic]`, `[First Name]`, `[Last Name]`, `[Insurance Nr]`, `[Marital status]`, `[Nr of Children]` etc. As a general purpose, if you *have to* use two words for your column names, you can write your works adjacent.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` instead of calling their `.Close()` and `.Dispose()` methods manually.

```
using(var myconection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
using(var mycomand = myconection.CreateCommand())
{
   //
}
```

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate upexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` overloads instead to specify your `OleDbType` and your parameter size.

As a final thing, `Picture` seems a form and report property in MS Access. That means it is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html). You need to use it `[Picture]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put your column names inside the square bracket.

```
[First Name],[Marital status],[Nr of Children],[Address],[Mother Tongue],[Other Languages],[Phone Nr]
```

So it would be like

```
mycomand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Refugees Characteristic]([Nr],[First Name],[Last Name],[Birthday],[Country],[City],[Insurance Nr],[Gander],[Marital status],[Nr of Children],[Address],[Mother Tongue],[Other Languages],[Phone Nr],[Enter to Austria],[Education],[Skills],[Picture]) VALUES (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16,@p17,@p18)";
```

Comment: I did all of them, but still hase the same problem

Comment: Why he would need to use it as verbatim literal? I don't see any character to escape it.

Comment: @Hani:- Probably the table name should also be put inside the bracket. Update my answer. Please check now!

Comment: I again did that, but still have the same Error

Comment: @Hani:- Please check the column names and table name if they are correct, also if they contain the space and all in the database.

Comment: The Column names and table name are coppied from dataset fields, can I send my application to you or somebody else?

Comment: @Hani:- Rest everything seems to be ok in your query. Can you try to remove the `@` just before the query and try again.

Comment: I did, now has a new error:"contains a new following field: 'Nr' '"

Comment: @Hani:- I guess thats because `Nr` is a primary key in your table. If yes then remove it from the query and also its value `@p1`

Comment: Contains unkown field name:'Nr'

Comment: @Hani:- Is `Nr` your primary key of the table?

Comment: I removed it from primary key, but still has the same problem

Comment: @Hani:- Try this: `mycomand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Refugees Characteristic]([First Name],[Last Name],[Birthday],[Country],[City],[Insurance Nr],[Gander],[Marital status],[Nr of Children],[Address],[Mother Tongue],[Other Languages],[Phone Nr],[Enter to Austria],[Education],[Skills],[Picture]) VALUES (@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16,@p17,@p18)";
`

Comment: Now it is not primary key, but still has the same Error: 'Nr'

Comment: @Hani:- ALso remove this line from your code:- `mycomand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", IdTxt.Text);
`

Comment: @Hani:- So that is for sure that there is some mismatch between the names of your column. Please verify it.

Comment: I removed all the fields which had 'Nr', now has a new error "data type mistmach"